# How to create values for different groups in "Device in Editor"?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to create different values to specify groups provided below?

[image: Device in Editor]

Answer (score 0):

You can provide alternative resources for different languages, screen sizes, orientation, etc.
Please, check this [article](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) to get additional details.
For example, you can look at first group of devices and notice that Nexus One and Nexus S uses `hdpi` screen, so to provide `drawable` resources for them, you can add `drawable-hdpi` folder:

[image]

Comment: I need to create values that will match the first group.

Comment: Which type of resources do you want to use (drawable, layout, ...)?

Comment: this not exactly what I mean. I need one folder with resources that will match devices from the first group (Nexus One - Nexus 5). What is in common in that devises? Why it is divided into groups and separated by line?